# Data are not send from view to template on Django

Tags: python, django

fapp/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import dhiraj

def index(request):
    t=dhiraj.objects.all()
    context={'dhiraj':t}

    return render(request,'fapp/index.html',context)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

index.html

```
<h1>this is</h1>

{% for taskk in dhiraj %}
<div>
<p>{{taskk}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class dhiraj(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I'm trying to access my object data in the template but it's not returning the right.

Comment: are you sure you populated the model with data?

Comment: yes data are 
DHIRAJ
 dhiraj object (4)
 dhiraj object (3)
 dhiraj object (1)

Comment: so actually this object (4) dhiraj object (3) dhiraj object (1)  are not showing in the template? under "this is"?

Comment: Have you checked the answers, mark one of these answers as accepted if it worked for you, and consider upvoting answers, that's how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

In the template Django does not know what to print because the task object has a lot of properties. You can either write:

```html
<p>{{taskk.title}}</p>
```

or you can specify the default method that will print it out for you:

```py
class Dhiraj(models.Model):
    #your other code
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `__str__` method to your dhiraj model, it seems like you put your string method in the views file.

that's why the `<p>{{ taskk }}</p>` is empty, but you can use `<p>{{ taskk.title }}</p>` to display the title.

Correct way to define `__str__` method:

```
class Dhiraj(models.Model): # Capitalized Model names are recomended
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="" )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```